# Jinja2 : call function on click

Tags: javascript, python, html, jinja2

I'm hacking a cms-like system that use Jinja2 and Javascript in frontend and Python in backend.

I implemented some Python functions on backend that do stuff on database.

I want to launch that functions from HTML pages, so i used Jinja2.

The problem is that the snippets `{% %}` and `{{ }}` are always parsed and processed when HTML is loaded.

I want to execute that functions when I click a button or a link.

How could I make it works?

Comment: Its not trivial... You CANNOT execute a function in python through jinja from the front end. You need to create an endpoint in python, something like: 'mydomain.com/api/function-i-need-to-call' and then from the client side have the js just hit that endpoint

Comment: What's wrong with AJAX?

Answer (score 4):

Jinja2 is a template engine. You are wrong about its use.

You could create a small app in some lightweight web framework, like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) or [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html), and route some ajax routes to expected methods.

Here is an example using Flask:

**backend.py**

```
import os
from json import dumps
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('cmd.html')

@app.route("/cmd")
def cmd():
    osname = os.uname()[3]
    print(osname)
    return dumps({'name': osname})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

As described in docs, templates must be in a folder called `template` inside the project folder.

**cmd.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function cmd(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "http://0.0.0.0:5000/cmd",
                    success: function (data) { 
                        $("#result").html("dfsdfds")
                  },
                });                
            }
         </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" onclick="return cmd();">Item</a>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

To execute it just run `python backend.py`. Open your browser and go to `http://127.0.0.1:500`

The app runs a command on backend and returns the result.